# Создание универсального ToModel в интерфейсе, возвращающий какой-либо класс C#

Tags: c#

Есть интерфейс, который объявляет метод

```
public T ToModel<T> () where T : class;
```

Реализация классов, реализующих этот интерфейс, требует, чтобы этот метод реализовался как-то так:

```
public MyModelClass1 ToModel<MyModelClass1> () {return new();}
public MyModelClass2 ToModel<MyModelClass2> () {return new();}
```

...
Как это можно реализовать? Пробовал так:

```
public T ToModel<T>() where T : class
    {
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(MyModelClass1))
            return new MyModelClass1()
            {
                
            };}
```

Не получилось.

Comment: `where T : class, new() { return new() }`, либо `return Activator.CreateInstance<T>();`

Comment: ну или `return new T()`

Comment: Спасибо, это решило мою проблему.